# Objective-C - Test connection of URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very very new to objective-c

I am trying to test a connection of a URL, I found this code here, but I have no idea where I put the URL

```
-(void) queryResponseForURL:(NSURL *)inURL {
  NSMutableURLRequest request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL];

  [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

  NSURLConnection connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  // connection starts automatically
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  if ( [(NSHTTPURLResponse  *)response statusCode] == 200 ) {
    // url exists
  }
}
```

Comment: `inURL`? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are very new to Objective-C, the important thing to know is that didReceiveResponse: will be called at an unknown time in the future, and at that point in the future you need to record that the URL could either be accessed or not.

But unless you have a very good reason, it's bad practice to check whether a URL is there or not. You just download the URL, and if it cannot be read, you will get an error, and you handle it. For example, just because the URL was there half a second ago doesn't mean it's there now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to test is whether you've internet connection or not. For that you can either access [Tony Million's Reachability](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability--mobile-18299) or Apple's rateability class.